# ¿Pór que mi formulario no envia nada a la funcion en laravel 9 y livewire 2.8?

Tags: web, formularios, laravel-livewire, livewire, laravel-9

## Problema con envío de campos a formulario

*Tengo un componente llamado **"Inspeccion"** el cual tiene su propia vista con livewire, el cual ya valide que si este conectado, pues inyecto datos a los campos con valores ya precargados.*

*Mi problema entra cuando hago cambios en los campos y quiero enviarlos a una funcion para poder enviar esos datos a un api, pero cuando hago un **dd()** este ni siquiera entra, hace una redireccion asi mismo, y al final pone una **?** en la URL.*

Asi es como envio los datos

```
<input class="buenEstado" type="checkbox" wire:model="inspeccionCortesia.alineacion"  id="alineacion" value="0" @if($inspeccionCortesia['alineacion'] == 0) checked @endif>
```

*Y **inspeccionCortesia** esta definido como un objeto, donde tomo cada valor y lo envio a la vista*

```
<form wire:submit.prevent='miFuncion(inspeccionCortesia)'>
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

a grandes rasgos asi es mi form, no pongo todos los campos por que son mas de 250, pero cuando presiono el boton, simplemente me redirecciona.

```
 public function miFuncion($datos)
    {
        dd($datos); // Para verificar que los datos se están actualizando
    }
```

*Mi simple funcion, solo tiene un dd*

Que estoy haciendo mal? necesito ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenía un problema del tipo **Root Element Issues**: tenía un elemento fuera del div, el cual causaba que los `wire:submit` y `wire:click`, no funcionaran.

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que la llamada:

```
          <form wire:submit.prevent='miFuncion(inspeccionCortesia)'>
```

este dando error y no hace la llamada , porque el parámetro o el objeto que estas pasando inspeccionCortesia no se evalúa correctamente.

Debería ser así :

```
          <form wire:submit.prevent='miFuncion($inspeccionCortesia)'>
```

o

```
          <form wire:submit.prevent='miFuncion($this->inspeccionCortesia)'>
```

De cualquier manera, como estas trabajando con Livewire, todos los objetos y las variables del componente los tienes actualizados siempre dentro del componente.

Lo que quiero decir es que no hace falta que le pases nada a la función.
porque dentro de la función miFuncion() podes acceder a los datos
llamando a la variable o al objeto asi:

```
           $this->inspeccionCortesia
```

entonces tu submit debería ser así:

```
         <form wire:submit.prevent='miFuncion()'>
```

Espero que te sirva. saludos

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, tristemente ninguna de las cosas que aconsejaste, no me funcionaron :( no me explico que este pasando

Comment: Podrías verificar si Livewire esta cargando correctamente. Verifica con las Herramientas del desarrollador del Navegador. si es que no tienen ningún error en la consola.

Comment: *He verificado y si!, era un problema del **Root Element Issues**, tenia un elemento fuera del div principal, lo que causaba que los form y datos no se enviaran correctamente